# Java File.isDirectory() returns false on network paths

Tags: java, file-io

The `isDirectory()` method of Java File objects seems to always return false on network paths. Is this expected? I tried doing some searches and couldn't find any information on using File with network paths. Here's what my code looks like:

```
ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();

files.add(new File("\\\\clouddrive\\somefolder\\somesubfolder"));

// S is a mapped network drive to "\\clouddrive\somefolder"
files.add(new File("S:\\somesubfolder"));

// prints
for (File f : files) {
  System.out.println(f.getPath() +" is directory? "+ f.isDirectory());
}
```

Additionally, `exists()` also returns false.

Comment: Sounds like a but in Java implementation which you use. What Java do you use? Is it the latest Java 7?

Comment: Were the network paths available at the time? This has been working for me since 1997.

Comment: Yeah this is the latest Java 7, and yes the network paths are available. I have it open in a windows explorer right next to me. I also made sure to remove any password restrictions. The network drive is a WD MyBook Live hard drive so maybe they did something weird?

Comment: Do the files exist in those directories if you manually bring them up?

Comment: Yes, the files in those directories exists in windows explorer. I just tried running the code while playing a video from that directory, and Java still shows me false.

Comment: What happens when you rerun this in your IDE as admin?

Comment: I'm running it manually via an admin command prompt "java test" (test is the test.java and test.class I built). I just imported it into eclipse, ran as admin, and still get the same results.

Comment: Any update of this subject???